# How to correctly structure a Python package so that it can be easily imported?

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python package which will contain re-usable code, classes etc that will be imported in to our other Python programs. I'm really struggling to get my imports to work correctly though, either the imports stop working due to changes in **init**.py or I'll get an ImportError.

### **init**.py:

```py
from .util import configParser, writeToAppLog # currently trying this method...
from .itm import normaliseAgentVersion
# from . import util                          # would prefer this method so we don't have to define every single thing our module will "export"
# from . import itm

__all__ = ["util", "itm"]
```

###### Note: I'd like to avoid using any kind of `import *` as it masks where functions get imported from...

### test.py:

```py
from . import itmlcm

itmlcm.normaliseAgentVersion("06.30.07.00")
```

The above test.py script seems to work, certainly within VS Code. However, it produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\LCM\bin\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import itmlcm
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

How can we structure this properly so that we can develop the package and also import it to use it in our code?

Comment: What is your project directory structure?

Comment: don't you mean `__init__.py`?

Comment: Have you been through [python's documentation on packaging python projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)?